# distance between two points using google map api URL ("Code not working")

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Code is not working propperly. 
when I remove variable from url and simple put location it works fine.
and also works fine when I assign postcode to variables.

```
<?php 
    $origin='Dover';
    $destination= 'London';
    /* print_r($destination);
    $size=sizeof($destination);
    echo $size; */
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false%27';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = utf8_decode($data);
$obj = json_decode($data);

echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text); //km
echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value); // meters    

?>
```

or is there any other way to get driving distance between two locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if that is the problem but your using single quote on your url string which means that your passing `$origin` instead of Dover to your api request

Use double quote in your `$url` definition like:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false%27";
```

Cheers